# Trying to create a 2D Array from a custom Object being a Pair class. Won't compile

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a 2D array of nodes which are basically 2D plot coordinates. The first column so to speak (ie. [0][0], [1,0] ...) will be the head element wheras all points in the same row following it are successors which link to the first point. From this I am implementing some simple search algorithms. The class I have created (MyPair) simply takes two arguments being aVal, bVal which are both ints. However I don't know how to put these custom objects a 2D array without compilation errors. A snippet of the code follows.

```
    public class GraphNodes {
public MyPair[][] graphNodes;

public GraphNodes(){
    this.graphNodes = new MyPair[][] 
            {{(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)},
            {(0,1), (0,0), (1,1), (0,2)},
            {(0,2), (0,3), (0,1)},
            {(0,3), (0,2), (0,4)},
            {(0,4), (0,3), (0,5)},
            {(0,5), (0,6), (1,5), (0,4)},
            {(0,6), (1,6), (0,5)},
            {(1,0), (0,0), (1,1), (2,0)},
            {(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,0), (0,1)},
```

I thought doing it this way would work but I am getting an error saying `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable` in eclipse. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post us the full class?

Comment: You just cant do anything even similar what you have to tried here... Look for 2D array tutorials, this is completely wrong from start to end :).

Comment: I do understand I just haven't coded in a while and am making really stupid mistakes I know. Basically just want to take this huge list and use it as a test for my breadth first search class. Just wondering what would be the easiest way. I can change to an arraylist implementation if necessary

Answer (score 1):

`(0,0)` cannot be converted by the compiler to your `MyPair` class automatically.

You have to invoke a constructor such as `new MyPair(0,0)` (assuming you have such a constructor).

If you have such a constructor, you can replace any `(x,y)` in your code with `new MyPair(x,y)`.

Comment: I am assuming there must be a quicker way to do such a thing? Would a 2D list be perhaps a better solution?

Comment: @PhillOliver If there's no logic in your MyPair class, you can replace it with an int array. Then your `MyPair[][]` 2D array will become a `int[][][]` 3D array whose 3rd dimension has 2 integers.

Comment: @PhillOliver If you must use your MyPair class, you'll have to create the instances with a constructor. Using a List instead of an array won't change that.

Comment: Basically the pair type is just to plot coordinates so could do that. There are some methods but could be overwritten easily. I may have to try that